# C++ Pointer usage

Tags: c++, pointers

I've started dealing with pointers thanks to the a library I used a bunch of years ago.

I knew what it did but I never knew why it was needed, although it was somewhat a prerequisite in the said library thanks to some functions.

So basically, it gives you the address of the variable although you could also access the content with it. 
(https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_pointers.htm)

And I tried searching why we exactly needed it.

It said on this [website](http://duramecho.com/ComputerInformation/WhyCPointers.html) that C (I'm assuming that the pointer in C is identical to that of C++) was created during a time when computers were not fast enough.

EDIT: I figured it would be voted as too broad, hope the one I chose right now isn't.

How exactly does access to the address itself prove beneficial over access to the variable itself?

EDIT: Got the answers I needed, feel free to close this.

Comment: it's not about the speed, the computers just have this "random access memory" thing and it implies pointers naturally

Comment: Pointers are needed to create and access in-memory data structures. You can do without them in higher level languages. Then they're used internally in the language's implementation.

Comment: Voted to close as **too broad** (it's also a bit subjective).

Comment: In C, there are things which *can* be done using pointers, like iterating over an array, and some things which *cannot* be done *without* pointers (passing a function as a parameter, or emulating output parameters i.e. call-by-reference). Hence, pointers are not included in C for performance reasons at all.

Comment: Even if computers are even faster today, we also try to do *way* more things than in the 1970's. And nowadays, doing something really fast will save battery capacity, which is very important.

Comment: @BoPersson Umm... no. Doing things really fast implies maximum CPU frequency working at 100%. To save battery capacity, you sleep as much as you can and work with as slow frequency as possible. But perhaps you are speaking of some PC laptop or smart phone.

Comment: Please throw both those websites into an incinerator. The first one is highly misleading, the second one is so wrong all the way through it's not even funny.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf gotcha, thanks. Thought I was missing out on a really big thing.

Comment: C and C++ are different languages. Handling pointers is not identical. Don't "assume" something and don't spam tags.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 1) So if computers are fast enough nowadays, then why am I still seeing some people using pointers? Is the speed difference really that big?

You are misunderstanding what pointers are for. A pointer is not some optional feature used only for performance gains, it is a fundamental part of both C and C++ languages, just like types, variables, arrays or functions.

In most cases, pointers are analogous to computer addresses. As long as computers will have addresses, there will be a need for pointers.

Other languages that don't have pointers simply hide them away beneath abstraction layers. And that's why you can't even write hardware-related programming in such high-level languages.

> 2) How exactly does it help with speed and how should I use it?

That question is too broad for Stack Overflow. There are a whole lot of completely different cases where pointers can be used for various optimizations.

> 3) Is it a good practice?

Depends on the situation. You are basically asking if it is good practice to use a screwdriver, without specifying what you intend to use it for.

Comment: "You are basically asking if it is good practice to use a screwdriver, without specifying what you intend to use it for.", well formulated. :)

Comment: _You are basically asking if it is good practice to use a screwdriver_, or, a hammer without a nail. :)

Answer (score 0):

Pointers are still needed. For example, when accessing a member of an object (say a function), sometimes you will need to use the `this` keyword. `this` represents a pointer to the object that called the function. Google **"c++ what are some uses of this keyword"** and you will find why pointers are needed.

A much simpler example:

```
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    std::cout << "Program name: " << argv[0] << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Command line arguments. Without pointers you could not even pass arguments into a C++ program (e.g. via terminal).

Comment: U now, u could mention the arguments of `main` and be done with it.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf That is very true. I will edit my answer to include that.